# How to resolve mismatched types error around reference that involves getting a value from a struct in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a wrapper type like this:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;

pub struct WrapPathBuff(pub PathBuf);
```

Which is part of a config struct like this:

```
pub struct Config {
    path: WrapPathBuff
}
```

I now want to implement a method on `Config` that returns `WrapPathBuff` but I keep running into compilation error, and I am afraid I do not understand the borrow checker well enough to fix the error.

So here is the implementation:

1st Attempt:

```rust
impl Config {
    pub fn get_path(&self) -> WrapPathBuff {
        &self.path
    }
}
```

This leads to the following compilation error

```
11 |     pub fn get_path(&self) -> WrapPathBuff {
   |                               ------------ expected `WrapPathBuff` because of return type
12 |         &self.path
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |
   |         expected struct `WrapPathBuff`, found `&WrapPathBuff`
   |         help: consider removing the borrow: `self.path`
```

Ok so it expects `WrapPathBuff` but it is getting `&WrapPathBuff`

2nd attempt:

```rust
impl Config {
    pub fn get_path(&self) -> WrapPathBuff {
        WrapPathBuff(&self.path.0.clone())
    }
}
```

The intention is to clone path, and not make it a reference and use that to create a totally new `WrapPathBuff` but this also fails with the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types   --> src/main.rs:18:22
   |
18 |      WrapPathBuff(&self.path.0.clone())
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                   |
   |                   expected struct `std::path::PathBuf`, found `&std::path::PathBuf`
   |                   help: consider removing the borrow: `self.path.0.clone()`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

First question...why does the first attempt not work?

Second question...why does `.clone()` not clone to an own variable instead of a cloned reference?

Third question...most importantly, how do I achieve what I want to achieve?

Here is the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2e7280da4d3fab1b0d24c9a2d16f659b) demonstrating the issue

Comment: It might be worth revisiting the concepts of [ownership and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html). A reference cannot be used where an owned value is expected (i.e. `WrapPathBuff`). The error message of the second attempt presents another hint. Did you try it?

Comment: For the first question, it complains that it expects something and got something else. You tried fixing it by changing what it gets, but maybe you could have changed its expectations instead? (ie. change the return type of `get_path`).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: Implement/derive `Clone` for `WrapPathBuff`:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct WrapPathBuff(pub PathBuf);

pub struct Config {
    path: WrapPathBuff
}

impl Config {
    pub fn get_path(&self) -> WrapPathBuff {
        self.path.clone()
    }
}
```

Another: do it manually in `get_path`:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;

pub struct WrapPathBuff(pub PathBuf);

pub struct Config {
    path: WrapPathBuff
}

impl Config {
    pub fn get_path(&self) -> WrapPathBuff {
        WrapPathBuff(self.path.0.clone())
    }
}
```

That said, I am unsure if you *really want* to have `get_path` return an owned thing (instead of returning a borrowed reference, and letting the callers clone it, if necessary).